# SSRS 2005 paging

Tags: reporting-services

How do I implement the Paging concept in ReportViewer in  SSRS 2005

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control that by the size of your page.  See [this article at msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/35f25f78-890f-482a-b2b7-5f318c311523/).  The report builder should do paging automatically for you.  If you are building your report in visual studio then you should see the "InteractiveSize" and "PageSize" attributes in the "Layout" section of the "Properties" Window.

Comment: Whoever did the minus would you mind explaining what is incorrect about my answer?  I see these settings in SSRS 2005 here so I'm not sure why this is wrong?  Unless I set something up I don't know about (which could be possible I guess), this stuff works fine for me here.